# oracle forms - lock procedure property

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have an oracle form, where the lock procedure property of a data block is set to call a procedure 'lock_fn'.
The procedure 'lock_fn' looks like below:

```
procedure lock_fn(outp IN OUT out_tab) IS
l_first BINARY_INTEGER := outp.first;
l_last BINARY_INTEGER := outp.last;
l_id a.id%type;
BEGIN
    for i in  l_first .. l_last loop
        select id
        into   l_id
        from a
        where a.id=outp(i).id;
    end loop;
END lock_fnl;
```

My question is, Would merely selecting the ids guarantee a row level lock?. Any help would be most welcome.

Edit:
The LOCK-PROCEDURE trigger of the data block has the code auto-generated that looks like below:

```
DECLARE
bk_data FRMPKG.OUT_TAB;
BEGIN
PLSQL_TABLE.POPULATE_TABLE(bk_data, 'LOCK_FN', PLSQL_TABLE.LOCK_RECORDS);
FRMPKG.LOCK_FN(bk_data);
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would merely selecting the ids guarantee a row level lock?

No. You'd need a SELECT FOR UPDATE (But then selecting just a single column would be sufficient).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Would the code in question do any good at all with regards to locking?. I found it in one of the  forms in production.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it does look like a no-op. Just selecting will not obtain any locks, and so will neither block anyone else nor be blocked by anyone else.